# Microsoft Office Interop Excel ExportAsFixedFormat - very slow, images not loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, interop, ms-office

I want to export generated .xlsx spreadsheet as PDF.
I have two problems:

- Exporting document is very slow for both method - SaveAs() ExportAsFixedFormat()
- ExportAsFixedFormat do not export the images.

I am running the code in ASP.NET server with IIS.

Already configured permissions like it says here : https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1129/66/access-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-e_accessdenied

The code from this repository works without error: https://github.com/aardvarkss/ExcelPDFExport

Also I generate .xlsx file with EPPlus.

The code:

```cs
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks excelWorkbooks = app.Workbooks;
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wkb = excelWorkbooks.Open(this.tempExcelFilePath);

   foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet in wkb.Sheets)
   {
        sheet.SaveAs(this.tempPdfFilePath); // Saves the PDF correct AS I want But it cannot finish the task (waiting around 3 mins)
        sheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, this.tempPdfFilePath); // Export PDF without image (image currently cannot be displayed), Also slow
   }

   wkb.SaveAs(this.tempPdfFilePath); // Waiting too long and cannot be finished
   wkb.ExportAsFixedFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, "C:\\Users\\user222\\Desktop\\Sample.pdf"); // Waiting too long and cannot be finish the task

   // Closes the EXCEL.exe process in windows. If it not closes it cause errors. 
   wkb.Close(SaveChanges: false);
   excelWorkbooks.Close();
   app.Quit();

   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wkb);
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkbooks);
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
```

Any ideas why it is so slow? And how to fix my problems?

The slow loading started today. before that, it doesn't have this problems with slow loading.

Comment: Interop is neither designed nor recommended to be used in server applications. Check in TaskManager if there is no orphaned EXCEL.EXE left.

Comment: When debugging just before reach the ` new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();` line, there are no EXCEL.EXE process in Task Manager.

Comment: Well, I suppose it should be something with either Excel or source files since it was working before today. Try to restat the server and see if it will make any difference.

Comment: Already tried. I am still on localhost, Restarted machine, IIS etc. I am still glitched here so  I've started to work with `iTextSharp` - row by row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am running the code in ASP.NET server with IIS.

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

I'd suggest using the Open XML SDK instead, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Also you may consider using third-party components designed for the server-side execution.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will agree with you. but using Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office is little complicated for me. I will use `iTextSharp` as alternative.